# My first proof employing the pigeonhole principle / dirichlet's box principle - very simple theorem on real numbers. Please mark/grade.

Tags: soft-question, proof-writing, proof-verification, pigeonhole-principle, real-numbers

What do you think about my first proof employing the pigeonhole principle? What mark/grade would you give me? Besides, I am curious about whether you like the style.

---

### Theorem

Among three elements of the unit interval,
        there are two whose distance is less than or equal to $\frac{1}{2}$.

### Proof

Let $I = [0,1]$ denote the unit interval.
        Let $x = (x_1, x_2, x_3) \in I^3$.
        The components of $x$ denote our three elements of the unit interval.
        It remains to prove that for two of them
        - the two will be denoted by $x_i$ and $x_j$, $i \ne j$ -
        we have $\left| x_i - x_j \right| \le \frac{1}{2}$.

For all components of $x$, the condition holds that the component is an element of $I$.
        We partition this condition into two cases, introdcuing the subintervals
        $I_1 = \left[ 0,\frac{1}{2} \right]$ and
        $I_2 = \left( \frac{1}{2}, 1 \right]$, as follows:

**Case 1:** The component is an element of $I_1$.
                By [this theorem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/734147/my-first-simple-direct-proof-very-simple-theorem-on-real-numbers-please-mark),
                a difference of elements of $I_1$ is less than or equal to $\frac{1}{2}$.

**Case 2:** The component is an element of $I_2$.
                We see that
                $I_2 \subset \left[ \frac{1}{2}, 1 \right]$.
                Hence, by the same theorem,
                a difference of elements of $I_2$ is less than or equal to $\frac{1}{2}$.

By the definitions of $I$, $I_1$, $I_2$, we see that the cases are collectively exhaustive;
        by the definitions of $I_1$, $I_2$, we see that the cases are mutually exclusive.
        Thus for each component, we have precisely one case.
        Hence, we may apply the pigeon-hole principle:
        We infer that there are two components, for which we have the same case.
        We denote these two components by $x_i$ and $x_j$ - where of course $i \ne j$.

Since for $x_i$ and $x_j$, we have the same case,
        $x_i$ and $x_j$ belong to the same subinterval.
        Hence, by the deductions that concluded the cases,
        introducing $d_1$ and $d_2$, we infer that

- $d_1 = x_i - x_j \le \frac{1}{2} \quad$ and
- $d_2 = x_j - x_i \le \frac{1}{2}$ .

Introducing yet another symbol $d = |x_i - x_j|$,
        we see that it remains to prove that $d \le \frac{1}{2}$.
        By the definition of absolute values, we have

$$d = d_1\quad \text{or}
\quad d = d_2\text{.}$$

For each of the two possibilites, using the above inequalities,
        we deduce that $d \le \frac{1}{2}$.
        By disjunction elimination, this proof is concluded.

Comment: Nothing wrong with that Draco. 10 points to Slytherin.

Answer (score 2):

You can shorten it though,  to this.

Note that among the two intervals $[0, 0.5]$ and $(0.5, 1]$, there must exist an interval with at least $2$ numbers. The difference between these numbers is clearly $\le 0.5$.